# How to "nofollow" paid advertising with internal redirect

Tags: redirects, advertising, nofollow, banners

We have a site which includes paid banner and sidebar ads (not part of an advertising network). The ads are simple images/gifs which are linked to the advertiser's (external) site.

The links go through an internal redirect like:

`example.com/advert-redirect?id=123&url=http://advertiser.com`.

What's the most appropriate way to apply a `nofollow` on this type of link?

I'm concerned that search engines will see this as a `nofollow` on internal links (when they're actually not).

One possible solution is to use `robots.txt` to block `example.com/advert-redirect`. Is this a suitable option?

Comment: Using a sneaky redirect to hide a outbound link would be considered cloaking and if your having to hide affiliates then your meeting their Quality guidelines on "Participating in affiliate programs without adding sufficient value" since good affiliates add value and if your having to hide them then that speaks a thousand words. Ditch the redirect and use a external link that both your visitors and search engines can see before clinking them.

Comment: @SimonHayter sorry, but what you said above is plain wrong. Here are some respected and knowledgeable people from the marketing niche with their - completely opposite - take:
[Rae Hoffman](https://sugarrae.com/affiliate-marketing/cloak-affiliate-links/)
[Aaron Wall](http://www.seobook.com/archives/001935.shtml)
[Joost de Valk](https://yoast.com/cloak-affiliate-links/)

Comment: Rubbish @Bartek, read Google's policy on Participating in affiliate programs... hiding it is in violation of their policy. Link to something official... far to busy to read blog posts from non Google employees.

Comment: @SimonHayter the redirects are in no way a "sneaky attempt to hide the outbound link". Its simply a mechanism which allows us to track clicks. The destination url is visible as part of the query string (although I appreciate not everyone will see this). Also, this is just simple banner ads for companies in a niche area - not an affiliate programme.

Comment: Your asked about nofollow and blocking via robots... and nothing about tracking... also you can track data without redirecting... wanting something to be true isn't going to make it true. Unless I have mistake... your scared that 301 redirect will reward externally?

Comment: Google doesn't respect the nofollow attribute internally since webmasters abused it for several years attempting to shape the flow of juice. A 301 redirect will pass 99% or more juice from site to site, there is no way of preventing this when using a redirect. You could however make link go to X page then redirect... using noindex on that page should prevent juice being passed out because Google does not reward or pass juice from pages that are not indexable.

Comment: You wanted something official, there you go: [Matt Cutts on video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31BA0rwnfk8)

Saying that "Google doesn't respect the nofollow attribute" is harmful and can do real damage, especially to beginners. You are wrong, why do you ask me to link official sources while in the same time you just post your opinions without any sort or documented backup?

Comment: He mentions nofollow and never mentions internal link once. Nofollow does not work on internal links. It hasn't for almost a decade. At no point have I said NOT to use nofollow on a external site. At no point have I said NOT to use nofollow on a external site.

Comment: @SimonHayter I was more concerned with the "Paid Links" section of https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en. My question was whats the best way to apply a nofollow (or similar) to an internal page which redirects to the advertiser's external page.

Comment: @SimonHayter Where did the OP ask about internal links?

Comment: `example.com/advert-redirect?id=123&url=http://advertiser.com.` <--- Looks internal to me...

Comment: It is a redirect, not an internal link. User gets 30x from such request, internal links are 200.

Comment: Using your domain with a query string is internal... the end result is external.  the redirect happens after you visit that page.

Comment: @James Paid links are fine just use the nofollow but you should avoid using a redirect. If you want to track stats for the adverts then you can use JavaScript or Google Analytics to track that data. Absolutely no reason to hide the URL from users or search engines, unless the adverts are ones that Google may dislike...

Comment: @SimonHayter so according to you, any SERP at Google is full of internal links, since they all go via google.com with params before user gets to any actual external page. This is way to much for me, EOT.

Comment: Correct Bartek... if you right click copy... you get a internal address `https://www.google.co.uk/url?` with the end result of a external address.. Your browser must go to Google before it can go to the end result, clearing demonstrating its a internal link with a 301 redirect which doesn't make it external. Anyway, doesn't matter what I say... you obviously believe this no matter what I say. To discuss this further we should enter a chat using the chat function.

Comment: @James Another method you could use is using Google's URL shortening service [goo.gl](https://goo.gl/) which will help you track external clicks on those links. Then use nofollow on that... that way you don't have to use Redirects, Google Analytics, JavaScript to track your external clicks.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thanks. Currently using GA event tracking and a (slightly archaic) method to track impressions/clicks (hence the redirect). An AJAX system is in the works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will work, but I do not understand what are you concerned about. Paid links/banners etc. should have `nofollow` tag (at least according to Google's guidelines, but that's something completely different). Technically, it does not matter whether you have it as link attribute or redirect via disallowed directory.

Another option is to use `X-Robots-Tag` as a [custom header](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag?hl=en). This approach is even better, because you are not disclosing in `robots.txt` what you don't want search engines to see/index (this is to protect mainly from your competition).

Answer (score 1):

**Both will work, and both will help you in paid advertising.**

The nofollow link is nofollow, it's don't care weather it is external or internal. It do same thing.

Special note : Google can crawl Nofollow links, so if they land on some advertising website, and see malicious and not safe content, then it might hurts your website. But it will be fine for most of paid advertising, when the landing page is good.

The robots.txt is something I recommended it in your case, because it completely block the Google spider. [Google own ads network use robots.txt](http://www.googleadservices.com/robots.txt) because if they use nofollow links, then it can be crawled and land on different website, based on Google User Agent, IP address, and device.

I know you're not redirecting anything, but you're using internal links redirect which is **very very easily handle by below robots.txt**

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /advert-redirect*
```